# Meteor Tracker.autorun doesn't update after changes in code structure

Tags: meteor

We are just about moving away from meteor in the backend (as the builds take longer and longer and other reasons) and have just moved a lot of core code (shared types, etc.) to a "shared" folder within our repository in order to use the type definitions in the new backend as well.

After three weeks of developing, I now wanted to test if the legacy meteor backend still worked. well, it does, however the legacy client which is also built by meteor suddenly wont do anything reactive.

The following code just prints "Tacker Update 0" and multiple times "Interval"

```js
let i = 0;
dep = new Tracker.Dependency()
Tracker.autorun(() => {
   dep.depend()
   console.log(`Tracker Update ${i++}`)
})

Meteor.setInterval(() => {
   dep.changed();
   console.log("Interval")
}, 1000);
```

When doing a

```js
Meteor.setInterval(() => Tracker.flush(), 100)
```

the tracker seems to "work", however that shouldn't be necessary, there is some obviously problem in the code that makes the Tracker non-functional, but I have no clue how to find it as git-bisect won't work here (made the new backend functional first while ignoring the old one with import paths etc).

Any ideas where I could look?

Comment: As you are suggesting already, the problem seems to be outside of the code you are showing. I would try to work out a minimal reproducible example in a fresh meteor project using the same meteor version as your current project.

Comment: well, if I was able to create such a minimal reproducible product, I very likely would have found the problem already.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but I don't really know how to help you with something I can't see because it is not included in the question. So if I was to try, then I would first try to create that very same reproducible example ... Perhaps someone else has a hunch where to look, which I guess is that what you are looking for.